# How fix error 500 Server Internal Error in post login?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm making an application with asp core 2.1 and Vue. My problem is the login to the production server (Windows Server 2012 R2). When I want to do login throws the following error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://{ip...}/api/account/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'error' of undefined at eval (Login.vue?03db:289)
```

All other endpoints respond except the login.

However, when I test in the development backend pointing to the production DB, it logs without problems and all the endpoints also respond (get, post etc). As far as I can understand it can be a configuration issue, maybe on the server related to IIS. As I understand if it were a matter of CORS no endpoint would work

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;

            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options => 
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ...
            });

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        services.AddCors();
        //Autorizacion a recursos de la aplicación
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(ConfigureJson);

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();


        }); 
    }


    private void ConfigureJson(MvcJsonOptions obj) {
        obj.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors(builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    );

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Program.cs

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
    }
```

Comment: Ignore the CORS error, it spits it out when there is a 500. What you need to do is wrap your login function in a try catch and use a logger to log the error to the file system. This way you can check what the error is. Alternatively you can make the method return the error as a bad request when you catch it.

Comment: You cannot use AJAX to hit an endpoint on `localhost` in production. The request is made from the client-side, and `localhost` on the client-side is the user's machine.

Comment: Finally I added environment variable in IIS and change URL size limit. it work. Log didn't show me relevant information. Thanks to both